# Trojan & Malware removal

Tags: security, malware

I have a Samsung Grand neo I9060, in which I recently downloaded an app from the web only for it to install malware and trojan in it. Each time the data connection is on or I'm connected to a wi-fi pop-up ads frequently appear which is pretty disguting. Efforts to uninstall this malware via apps from play store have all been futile.
The device is not rooted.
Kindly assist if you can, please.

Comment: Run [Malwarebytes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware) - it can remove malware but not all. If the problem persists update your question with results

Comment: That is not trojan, just to know. However you can flash stock firmware to get rid of that, maybe it's overkill but it will help. I have feeling like we are in 2005. again when people clicked on ads "you are 999999999 user who visited this page enter cc details to get reward". Watch your clicks people it's not that hard and don't download cracked .apk from everywhere.